# Is there a way to know a server is up?

Tags: c#, sockets

Say I have a server that when up either transmits a series of messages OR stays silent (but echoes if sent something).

**Is there a way to build a client (in C#) that connects to this server as soon as this server is up?**

I can not do polling as this will use all the CPU.

I've attempted both synchronous and asynchronous connects, but say the server is down, these connects will fail after a while (sometimes a very short time) and then retry it again would be just like polling.

---

A second question: If I use:

`clientSocket.BeginConnect("x.x.x.x", yyyy, new AsyncCallback(OnConnect), clientSocket);`

and then a function called `AsyncCallback` to finish the connection, how do I control (or can I?) the time it spends waiting for the connection to connect or fail??

Comment: You can't build a client that connects as soon as the server is up, but you might implement a server that informs the client as soon as the server is up.

Comment: If you have several questions, please ask them as individual questions.

Comment: Just let the client send a connecting message with interval of 5 seconds. When it can't connect try again and again until the server picks up the signal and accepts the client.

Comment: @ThomasWeller How do you do that? I mean the server will inform the client... but then how do this client will receive the inform? (without constant polling?) Something like an interrupt I mean

Comment: @DaPosto I suppose that is the way. So in that direction(I know I can just put some threadsleep but)  is there a way I can control the time of the AsyncCallback?

Comment: No, there isn't. You would just delay a packet that was already received. It does not make sense.

Comment: simple example why it not will work: ( If you want the server to send an message when it is listening for connections to the clients how should the client receive that message if it isn't connected to that server and isn't listening to server.) the best way is to check if you can connect in an certain interval to the server and CPU usage should not problem here.

Comment: The server is outside of the clients control. This means that as *soon* as you have determined as answer to the question "is the server up", and *before* you take any further action upon that answer, the answer may be out of date. Not to mention, of course, that there's also the network to consider, services running on the server, etc. The *only* reliable way to answer the question "can I do X against a remote service?" is to actually attempt to do X. No amount of "pre-checking" will answer the question accurately.

Comment: The is what Ping is used for.  Ping will check if the Server is running, but not any applications.  So it will check the IP and not the Port number.